# Google PageSpeed Insight problem with linkid.js

Tags: google-analytics

I spent weeks with optimising my site. One anoying problem has left:

http://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/linkid.js (60 min) how can I change the browser caching period or caching this file localy on D7 like analytics.js?

Comment: You can't change it for that file, because it's on Google's servers. I'm not sure that storing the file locally would work either. Why do you want to change this?